# How to create custom slider JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 4 div, 2 of them hidden. I put arrows left and right. And my idea is the following: when the left arrow is clicked, the two visible divs are hidden and the next two are shown. And it should be like that, circular. 
[image]

The same goes for the right arrow.

This is the html I have:

```
       <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3" id="left">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-1x"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3" id="test1">
    <div class="testimonial">
        <blockquote>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
            consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus
            accusamus expedita repellat similique
            odio aspernatur ex, architecto eaque
            quo suscipit.
        </blockquote>
        <div></div>
        <img src="Images/user1.png" style="float: left; padding-right:25px; padding-left:20px;">
        <p style="float:right; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;">
            <h3>John S.</h3> <span style="font-size: 13px; color: #a9aaac;">Freelancer</span>
        </p>
    </div></div>
    <div class="col-3" id="test2">
        <div class="testimonial">
            <blockquote>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus
                accusamus expedita repellat similique
                odio aspernatur ex, architecto eaque
                quo suscipit.
            </blockquote>
            <div></div>
            <img src="Images/user1.png" style="float: left; padding-right:25px; padding-left:20px;">
            <p style="float:right; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;">
            <h3>John S.</h3> <span style="font-size: 13px; color: #a9aaac;">Photographer</span>
            </p>
        </div></div>
    <div class="col-3" id="test3">
        <div class="testimonial">
            <blockquote>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus
                accusamus expedita repellat similique
                odio aspernatur ex, architecto eaque
                quo suscipit.
            </blockquote>
            <div></div>
            <img src="Images/user1.png" style="float: left; padding-right:25px; padding-left:20px;">
            <p style="float:right; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;">
            <h3>John S.</h3> <span style="font-size: 13px; color: #a9aaac;">Freelancer</span>
            </p>
        </div></div>
    <div class="col-3" id="test4">
        <div class="testimonial">
            <blockquote>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus
                accusamus expedita repellat similique
                odio aspernatur ex, architecto eaque
                quo suscipit.
            </blockquote>
            <div></div>
            <img src="Images/user1.png" style="float: left; padding-right:25px; padding-left:20px;">
            <p style="float:right; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;">
            <h3>John S.</h3> <span style="font-size: 13px; color: #a9aaac;">Photographer</span>
            </p>
        </div></div>

    <div class="col-3" id="right">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-1x"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the Jquery I have, that doesn't work really good:

```
      $("#test3").hide();
$("#test4").hide();



$("#left" ).click(function() {
    $( "#test1" ).toggle( "slide" );
    $("#test2").toggle("slide");
    $("#test3").show();
    $("#test4").show();
```

The issue is when I click on the arrow the two div are hidden and the other two are shown, but it is not smoothly like a carousel. they first appear on the row below and then take the place of the first two divs. If I click on the left arrow again, the first two appear but the last two remain. How do I hide them again? Since it is a toggle function I realize that it can't be done, but I will be grateful for any ideas.

Comment: Exactly what does _"doesn't work really good"_ mean? We need you to post the specific issue and a [mcve]

Comment: Please post your code in text format inside of your post.  And include the relevant information (like the quotes and etc.)